# How can I display content from one node to another?

Tags: 7, entities

With some design in mind, I have to display the some content of one node to another node. For ease of understanding, I have just put some drawing.

Suppose, I have,

`Content type`: **Article** which has -> **Node/5** which has -> **field_123** (Text type)

and I want to show that field content to another node,

`Content type`: **Basic Page** which has -> **Node/6** which will be ->  **copy_field_123** (Text type)

Hence, in short I want to display content of one node to another node. *I do not want entire node content to be transferred to another node as it is, but a specific fields which I choose.*

> [image]

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: and don't you want to use entity reference?

Comment: I am open to use any module, no restrictions. I have not used entity reference, I have assumption that it provides just link to that content. I will further check that module, if I can get it done with that.

Comment: I think ER is the way to go. It has integration with node display settings, views etc.

Comment: It doesn't just link to other content. Entity Reference will let you build a view to show that node's content. The CSS can be done by adding the node type's id selector.

Comment: @NiallMurphy, Thanks for suggestions, I will just try in my trial site. If it show specific field to  specific node, Then this will be the solution. Will let you know guys.

Comment: You should create a view block or use panels I think.

Comment: @NiallMurphy Yes, that will be one of the option. But for now, I wan to get it done using core modules as much as I can. Hence, I am looking for some thing which just allow me to get that field in another node. But, if not achievable, I will go for those.

Comment: NiallMurphy + @drupality, Just to update, I did check, but Entity reference does not have the feature of selecting particular field from particular node. It allows me to choose particular node. But after that there is not a option to choose particular field. Suppose that node has 6 fields, and I want to choose only content of 4th field(I mean 4th field).

Comment: @drupality Thanks for your inputs, I think Field reference will be the right module. Again any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: @NiallMurphy Thanks for your inputs, I think Field reference will be the right module. Again any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Selecting the node is fine. When you create a view after, you can just select the fields you want.

Answer (score 3):

I think after some research I found the solution. Again Thanks to [@Niall Murphy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/53677/niall-murphy) and 
[@drupality](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1178/drupality) For their input.

I think for my purpose [Field Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_reference) will be the right module. As it not only allows to choose the particular node, but which field you want to choose from that particulate node.

Although any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Nice research :)

Comment: @drupality Haha...it is not a research, but I just found as I tried ER but it was fetching whole content, so I thought to check whether there are other reference modules are there or not, And found FR. So, automatically  'Research' word came to mind..funny..:)

Comment: You can always use custom display for your node and add there single field. IMHO you can do this by ER also.